# Pythonic way of updating value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this current code

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
c = dict((el,0) for el in lst)
for key in lst: 
    c[key] += increase_val(key)
```

Is there a more pythonic way to do it? Like using map? This code words but i would like probably a one-liner or maybe better way of writing this

Comment: Why are you taking the keys from the list instead of the dictionary?

Comment: Well i could update it based on the dictionary as well i guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, that is a very clean, readable way of updating the dictionary in the way you wanted.

However, if you are looking for a one-liner, here's one:

```
new_dict = {x: y + increase_val(x) for x, y in old_dict.items()}
```

What's different is that this create's a new dictionary instead of updating the original one. If you want to mutate the dictionary in place, I think the plain old for-loop would be the most readable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

In your case no need of `c = dict((el,0) for el in lst)` statement, because we create dictionary where value of each key is `0`.

and in next for loop you are adding increment value to `0` i.e. 0 + 100 = 100, so need of addition also.

You can write code like:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
c = {}
for key in lst: 
    c[key] = increase_val(key)
```

---

**collection.Counter()**

Use `collections.Counter()` to remove one iteration over list to create dictionary because default value of every key in your case is `0`.

Use **Collections** library, `import collections`

**Demo:**

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4]
>>> data = collections.Counter()
>>> for key in lst:
        data[key] += increase_val(key)
```

---

**`collection.defaultdict()`**

We can use `collections.defaultdict` also. Just use `data = collections.defaultdict(int)` in above code. Here default value is zero.

But if we want to set default value to any constant value like `100` then we can use `lambda` function to set default value to `100`

**Demo:**

```
>>> data = {}
>>> data["any"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'any'
```

Get key error because there is on `any` key in dictionary.

```
>>> data1 = collections.defaultdict(lambda:0, data)
>>> data1["any"]
0
>>> data1 = collections.defaultdict(lambda:100, data)
>>> data1["any"]
>>> 100
```

Comment: this is cool, but would a more generic solution be to use a `collections.defaultdict`?

Comment: @maxymoo: yes, we can use `data = collections.defaultdict(int)` also.